# SQL Timestamp in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psql, datetime-format

I'm trying to understand the raw manner in which PostgreSQL saves `timestamp` data types. I get 2 different results depending on the client I use:

**1. psql**

```
# SELECT date_incorporated FROM client;

   date_incorporated    
------------------------
 2017-06-14 19:42:15-04
```

**2. [records](https://github.com/kennethreitz/records) python module**

```
rows = db.query('SELECT date_incorporated FROM client')
print(rows[0])
# {"date_incorporated": "2017-06-14T19:42:15-04:00"}
```

---

Since the `psql` interface and [records](https://github.com/kennethreitz/records) module are both supposed to be giving me back the raw data, I can't understand why both are giving me back different formats of the timestamp they have stored.

*The two differences I see so far are the `T`'s in the middle between the date and time in the [records](https://github.com/kennethreitz/records) version, and also the differing ways in which it shows the time zone at the end of the string*

Is one of them altering it? Which one is showing the real data?

Comment: The records apparently uses its own timestamp format which differs from the default Postgres format. But both string represent the same timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html

> All timezone-aware dates and times are stored internally in UTC. They
>   are converted to local time in the zone specified by the TimeZone
>   configuration parameter before being displayed to the client.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-OUTPUT

> The output format of the date/time types can be set to one of the four
>   styles ISO 8601, SQL (Ingres), traditional POSTGRES (Unix date
>   format), or German. The default is the ISO format.

EG:

```
t=# select now();
              now
-------------------------------
 2017-11-29 09:07:31.716276+00
(1 row)

t=# set datestyle to SQL;
SET
t=# select now();
              now
--------------------------------
 11/29/2017 09:07:52.341416 UTC
(1 row)
```

so the time is saved not the way it is returned. at least not neseserely. You can control up to some level how it it returned to your client. `psql` does not process time. but `python` does. not `records` I believe but `python` itself

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

> T is the time designator that precedes the time components of the
>   representation.

And that `T` is definetely not added by postgres itself (unless you deliberately format the date with `to_char`)